# JSON parsing in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have no idea how to parse JSON in java(or anything else). I've seen some tutorials but I can't get it straight.

I am trying to get `title="Fabiola Jean and Laurent Lundy commented on a photo that you're tagged"`. All I need is to know how to create a getTitle() method
this is the JSON I want to parse:

```
Connection[data=[Notification[id=notif__161136848 metadata=null
title=Fabiola Jean and Laurent Lundy commented on a photo that you're tagged in. type=null]]

nextPageUrl=https://graph.facebook.com/811204509/notifications?fields
    =title&value=1&format=json&redirect=1&access_token=MY_TOKEN&__paging_token=
    notif__161136848

     previousPageUrl=https://graph.facebook.com/811204509/notifications?fields=title
&value=1&format=json&redirect=1&access_token=MY_TOKEN&limit=5000&since=1342109329&
            __paging_token=notif__161136848&__previous=1 next=true previous=true]
```

Comment: Check [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: This doesn't look like a JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the code you put in your question is absolutely not valid JSON. I'm not quite sure what it is, and it does not appear to be easily parsable.

Assuming you are trying to parse actual JSON you almost certainly want to use a 3rd party library instead of writing the code using string manipulation functions.

[Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) would be my first recommendation, and [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) is another alternative you might want to look at.

Comment: It's the JSon that is returned when I try to get my notification from Facebook using restFb. Thank you,I will take a look at GSON